# Permissions on `brew` and `pip3`

Tags: homebrew, permission, python

Somehow permissions have been altered on brew and/or pip3 and both are getting errors.

brew has a lock file but when I remove it with sudo, brew commands say it iw still there.  pip3 worked to install mat, but it told me I should update pip3.  However, running the command it said to use gets a permissions error.

I would think that restoring from Time Machine would fix it, but I'm not quite sure what directories to restore.  I don't want to 'restore' something else that was legitimately changed.

Update: brew gives a different message after reboot:

```
WGroleau@MBP ~ % brew update
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/lock.sh: line 29: /usr/local/var/homebrew/locks/update: Permission denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from -e:1:in `<main>'
    1: from -e:1:in `new'
-e:1:in `initialize': Bad file descriptor (Errno::EBADF)
Error: Another active Homebrew update process is already in progress.
Please wait for it to finish or terminate it to continue.
```

before, it was almost the same, but it also gave the path/name of a lock file, which I deleted, only to find a retry complained about the same file.

I did NOT run another home-brew process in parallel.

I examined the script mentioned above.  Line 29 was not helpful, but a different part of the script had an error message about permissions and suggested
`sudo chown -R \$(whoami):staff /usr/local/var/homebrew`
which enabled brew to START running and do a lot, but then started complaining "no such file" in the "Cellar" and also mentioning symlinks.  So I tried
`sudo chown -R \$(whoami):staff /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local\Homebrew /usr/local\Frameworks`
and that allowed `brew upgrade` to run a lot further.  But I still got "Error: Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/share/locale/am/LC_MESSAGES/glib20.mo".

Perhaps `brew` can only be run by the account that installed it … yes (sigh)

Comment: What are the exact errors and command line used?

Comment: You can find and restore the exact files of brew and pip3 and brew via time machine with the commands “which brew” and “which pip3”. These will each return a path of an executable that time machine can restore. In finder, press shift + command + . to display the hidden and/or system files and folders that the utilities are located in

Comment: I think it's more than just the two executables.  But maybe the entire /usr/local  Anything else would be risky, as I updated to OS 11.6 since the last backup.

Answer (score 1):

`brew` should only be run by the account that installed it.

But first, I have to reverse the chown commands I ran under a different account with

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):staff /usr/local/var/homebrew \
                              /usr/local/Homebrew \
                              /usr/local/Cellar \
                              /usr/local/Frameworks
```

Then `brew upgrade` ran without error in that account.

Comment: There is a reason /usr/local should be updated by root and not an individual user :)

Comment: A command similar to that is what brew requested when it was getting errors.  It works now.

Comment: @mmmmmm Homebrew thinks it's a feature that they trash /usr/local.

Comment: /usr/local _was_ updated by root (sudo).  Only the subdirs installed by home-brew are owned by the installing account.